# Angular js + ng-repeat + alphanumeric index not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have created one Nav Controller in Angular JS as mentioned below.

```
weatherApp.controller('navCtrl', ["$scope", "$localStorage", function($scope, $localStorage){

    if($localStorage.user_email){
        var navItems = new Array();
        navItems["/"] = 'Home';
        navItems["/logout"] = 'Logout';
        $scope.navItems = navItems;
    }
    else{
        var navItems = new Array();
        navItems["/"] = 'Home';
        navItems["/login"] = 'Login';
        $scope.navItems = navItems;
    }
    $scope.test = "test";
}]);
```

I am calling this controller in index.html as shown below.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" ng-controller="navCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="(url, navItem) in navItems">
        <a href="#{{ url }}">{{ navItem }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

if I keep **navItems** indexes alphanumeric then it does not load values but if I keep its indexes numeric, it show menu items.

Is there any way by which I can use alphanumeric indexes in ng-repeat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a diferent data structure. Something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/relferreira/3aexpfk5/

JS:

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app')
    .controller('MainController', mainController);

mainController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function mainController($scope){

    var vm = this;

  vm.navItems= [
    { path: '/', name: 'Home'},
    { path: '/login', name: 'Login'},
  ];

}
```

HTML:

```
<div data-ng-app="app">

  <div data-ng-controller="MainController as mainVm">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ng-repeat="navItem in mainVm.navItems">
            <a href="#{{ navItem.path }}">{{ navItem.name }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for ng-repeat is correct.

However, do not use Array. Initialize your objects as:

```
var navItems = {};
```

As a side note, keeping user email in LocalStorage sounds like a very unusual thing (if this is a client-server app), but of course this ultimately depends on your use case.